# How to format axis real time amcharts hh:mm?

Tags: real-time, amcharts, formatdatetime

I use amchart, I want to create a real time chart, and set minDate, maxDate for x axis, and format it to hh:mm. I tried use `minimumDate, maximumDate, "minPeriod" : "hh"`, but it fail.

My code: 
[demo1](https://jsfiddle.net/TaNoBi/dtbx32r3/).

I want to use amchart to build a real time chart like: [demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/TaNoBi/hwf7rp5r/) (use flot chart).

The labels xaxis is static not run, and to accumulate data.
Help me, please!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating the time, you need to set a new date instance or a separate value. Updating the `startDate` variable updates all the data points that share that date object as AmCharts doesn't clone the date objects in your dataProvider. A quick fix is to use the millisecond timestamp result from the setMinutes call, for example:

```
var newDate = startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 10);
var visits = randomIntFromInterval(50, 100);

chartData.push({
  date: newDate,
  visits: visits
});
```

AmCharts will internally convert the millisecond values to a new Date object. This should be applied to your generate and update methods.

[`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) should be set to the minimum period between your datapoints. As you're adding data in 10 minute increments, this should be `"mm"`, *not* `"hh"`.

By default, the `categoryAxis` does not support setting a `minimumDate` and `maximumDate`, however, you can use AmCharts' [datePadding plugin](https://github.com/amcharts/tools/tree/master/datePadding) to add this functionality. This plugin will allow you to set a `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` property in your `categoryAxis` when you add the following script tag after your AmCharts includes:

```
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/tools/datePadding/datePadding.min.js"></script>
```

In order to maintain your date range after updating the chart, you have to call the plugin's `AmCharts.datePaddingProcess` method to re-update the range before redrawing the chart.

Here's what your updateChart method will look like after using the datePadding plugin:

```
function updateChart() {
  var newDate = startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 10);
  var visits = randomIntFromInterval(50, 100);
  chart.dataProvider.push({
    date:newDate,
    visits:visits
  });
  AmCharts.datePaddingProcess(chart, true);
  chart.validateData();
}
```

And here's what your categoryAxis will look like:

```
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "gridAlpha": 0.15,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "minPeriod" : "mm",
    "minimumDate": min,
    "maximumDate": max
  },
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtbx32r3/2/)

Comment: Hi @xorspark, Thank you very much! This worked for me :) (y)